# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'use' (T_USE) in C:\wamp\www\calculater\wp-content\themes\calculater\page.php on line

Tags: php, wordpress, namespaces, syntax-error

```
ob_start();  
require_once '\dompdf\autoload.inc.php';

use Dompdf\Dompdf;

 //use Dompdf\Dompdf;

// instantiate and use the dompdf class
$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$html = "
print_r($_POST);
";

$dompdf->loadHtml($html);
$dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'landscape');
$dompdf->render();
$pdf = $dompdf->output();
file_put_contents("page.pdf", $pdf);

?>  
<a href="./page.pdf" download="page.pdf">Download the pdf</a>
   <?php
exit;
?>
```

I try to do downloadable PDF script but getting parse error.

Comment: Tell us more information to proceed.

Comment: Use statements need to be at the top of the file

Comment: Are you running PHP >= 5.3.0, right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have problem with use of [use](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php):)

> The use keyword must be declared in the outermost scope of a file (the
>   global scope) or inside namespace declarations. This is because the
>   importing is done at compile time and not runtime, so it cannot be
>   block scoped.

Try this code:

```
use Dompdf\Dompdf;

ob_start();  
require_once '\dompdf\autoload.inc.php';

// instantiate and use the dompdf class
$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$html = "
print_r($_POST);
";

$dompdf->loadHtml($html);
$dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'landscape');
$dompdf->render();
$pdf = $dompdf->output();
file_put_contents("page.pdf", $pdf);

?>  
<a href="./page.pdf" download="page.pdf">Download the pdf</a>
   <?php
exit;
?>
```

Comment: Is this full text of your php file? What error do you have this time?

Comment: $file_location = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."pdf/".$pdf.".pdf";
file_put_contents($file_location,$pdf);  is not working   pdf save to all time different name                                                                                                          Warning: file_put_contents() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path,